# Is it essential to have a connection in a aws glue job?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have my data tables in the Glue Metadata catalog. I need to use this data in my glue job's python shell script. When I create the glue job it gives me the option to select the connection type at last. Is it essential to add a connection? If the tables are in glue catalog what would be the connection type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tables are in the Glue Catalog you don't need any connections. As long as your data sources / data sinks are Glue / S3 you don't need a connection apart from a VPC S3 Endpoint.

If you want to connect to let's say Redshift or a MySQL database you would need a connection.

Comment: To be more clear,does that mean I need to add VPC S3 Endpoint(Network connection) if my data is already available in glue catalog? Actually I got data to glue catalog by setting up a crawler which takes tata from S3 bucket.In that case do I have to add the S3 connection(Network as connection type)?

Comment: Yes you do. Your Glue jobs are in a private VPC and the requests need to be routed to S3.